# Theming the components through mixins doesn't seem to work anymore after upgrading from angular 11 to 12

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, angular-material, angular12

I'm trying to update my custom theme from Angular Material 11 to 12.
My problem is when i want to include my mixins they are not imported anymore.

Below a very light version of my code:

**My angular 11 code (worked before upgrading to angular 12)**

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;
@mixin mat-slide-toggle-theme($theme) {
  $is-dark: map_get($theme, is-dark);
  $primary: map-get($theme, primary);
  $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
  $warn: map-get($theme, warn);
  $background: map-get($theme, background);
  $foreground: map-get($theme, foreground);

  $thumb-unchecked-hue: if($is-dark, 400, 50);
  $thumb-checked-hue: default;

  $bar-unchecked-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($foreground, disabled);
  $ripple-unchecked-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($foreground, base);

  .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    @include _mat-theme-elevation(1, $theme);
    background-color: red; // For example
  }

}

@include mat.slide-toggle-theme($nest-theme);
```

**EXPECT** mat-slide-toggle-thumb to have background-color to equal red

**RESULT** mat-slide-toggle-thumb has background-color equal to red

**My sass code with angular 12**

```
@use '~@angular/material' as mat;
@use 'sass:map';
@use '~@angular/material/core/style/private';
@use '~@angular/material/core/theming/palette';
@use '~@angular/material/core/theming/theming';
@use '~@angular/material/core/typography/typography';
@use '~@angular/material/core/typography/typography-utils';

@mixin _checked-color($palette, $thumb-checked-hue) {
  &.mat-checked {
    .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
      background-color: theming.get-color-from-palette($palette, $thumb-checked-hue);
      background-color: red !important;;
    }
  }
}

@mixin color($config-or-theme) {
  $config: theming.get-color-config($config-or-theme);
  $is-dark: map.get($config, is-dark);
  $primary: map.get($config, primary);
  $accent: map.get($config, accent);
  $warn: map.get($config, warn);
  $background: map.get($config, background);
  $foreground: map.get($config, foreground);

  $thumb-unchecked-hue: if($is-dark, 400, 50);
  $thumb-checked-hue: default;

  $bar-unchecked-color: theming.get-color-from-palette($foreground, disabled);
  $ripple-unchecked-color: theming.get-color-from-palette($foreground, base);

  .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    @include private.private-theme-elevation(1, $config);
    background-color: red !important; // FOR EXAMPLE
  }

}

@mixin typography($config-or-theme) {
  $config: typography.private-typography-to-2014-config(
      theming.get-typography-config($config-or-theme));
  .mat-slide-toggle-content {
    font-family: typography-utils.font-family($config);
  }
}

@mixin _density($config-or-theme) {}

@mixin theme($theme-or-color-config) {
  $theme: theming.private-legacy-get-theme($theme-or-color-config);
  @include theming.private-check-duplicate-theme-styles($theme, 'mat-slide-toggle') {
    $color: theming.get-color-config($theme);
    $density: theming.get-density-config($theme);
    $typography: theming.get-typography-config($theme);

    @if $color != null {
      @include color($color);
    }
    @if $density != null {
      @include _density($density);
    }
    @if $typography != null {
      @include typography($typography);
    }
  }

  // I tried here it too with no success
  .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
    @include _mat-theme-elevation(1, $theme);
    background-color: red !important;
  }

}

// the include below doesn't seems to work even if i change @mixin theme to @mixin slide-toggle-theme
// @include mat.slide-toggle-theme($nest-theme);
```

**EXPECT** mat-slide-toggle-thumb to have background-color to equal red

**RESULT** mat-slide-toggle-thumb has NOT background-color equal to red

I've also tried to use `@use` and `@forward` but with no success, it seems that the project only compile and use the one (slide-toggle-theme) from material and not mine

@forward './slide-toggle/slide-toggle-theme' as slide-toggle-* show slide-toggle-theme,
slide-toggle-color, slide-toggle-typography;

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found my error:

In my custom theme I need to import and include the custom slide-toggle-theme :

```
@use './components/slide-toggle/_slide-toggle-theme' as slide-toggle-theme;
// all the theming configuration
$my-primary: mat.define-palette($mat-custom);
$my-accent:  mat.define-palette($mat-accent, A200, A100, A400);
$my-warn:    mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);
// Create the theme object
$my-theme: mat.define-light-theme($my-primary, $my-accent, $my-warn);

// including Nest theme
@include mat.all-component-themes($my-theme);
@include slide-toggle-theme.theme($my-theme);
```

DOC: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

Comment: If you answered your own question feel free to mark this answer as accepted so others know that it is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue using this new syntax (`mat.all-component-theme`)
take a look

```
@use "~@angular/material"as mat;
@import "~angular-material-css-vars/main";

@include init-material-css-vars(); // so i can use other color palette
@include mat-css-set-palette-defaults($mat-blue-grey, 'primary');

$theme-primary: mat-palette($mat-blue-grey);
$theme-accent: mat-palette($mat-yellow);
$theme-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$theme: mat.define-light-theme((color: (primary: $theme-primary, accent: $theme-accent, warn: $theme-warn)));

@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```